# Are there any configs to increase performances of my DO droplet?

Tags: performance, apache, server, digital-ocean

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean and it becomes really slow some times when I have 30-40+ users at the same time. I don't know if its the droplets capacity or my code I didn't optimise well, but it's starting to become annoying. Are there any tips to inscrease the speed of my droplet?

Here's my droplet configs:
[image]

What can I do? Should I transfer on another hosting service? Is there any configs or options I can edit or add to my droplet to increase my server's speed?

EDIT:

Sorry, I should've specified what is it my droplet is running!
I'm actually running a Laravel 5.8 app with a MySQL database. I did my own multi-tenants system so people can have their own version of my app (ex.: People can create leagues that will create a database for each league, and every leagues are independant).

I'm not familiar with all of that, but when I do the `htop` command on my server I get this, I believe there is one mysqld process for each league (database) on my web app.
[image]

Comment: We can't tell what your performance problems are because we have no idea what you are running other than that it's on a DO droplet.

I guess you're running Apache, but what's Apache serving up?  Static pages?  Apps?  What are the apps written in?  What do the apps do?  Are they accessing a database?  What database?

Comment: Indeed, I should've specified much more, take a look at the edit I made.

Comment: Consider having a 6G swap space on your server at DO.  Let us know how it works out with this single change.  You may have to contact DO to make this happen.

Comment: Additional information request . (either now or after you have swap space available).
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server at DO? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: SHOW GLOBAL STATUS --> https://pastebin.com/QgfbtC2n

SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES --> https://pastebin.com/mcCW3PfG

SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST --> https://pastebin.com/iiEgJdmw

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS --> https://pastebin.com/Re65rN7f

Comment: Thanks, server workload tuning analysis has started.  We will try to have Suggestions in an Answer within 24 hours.

Comment: This question is closed and so you won't be able to make answers, and folks wouldn't see it anyway.  I suggest that you do some research into where your problems lie and find out what is slow.  We can't help you speed up without knowing what's slow.  When you have a more focused question, post a new one.

Comment: Questions to look into: Are there certain user behaviors that are slower than others?  Do some pages take longer to return than others?  Are there some database queries that are slower than others?  Are there some database queries that are called a lot and take up a lot of time.  Also, since you're using PHP, you can look at using a tool like xdebug to find your hotspots.

You have to know what's slow in order to know what to speed up.

Comment: @ettdro Does your server use SSD or NVME for data storage?

Comment: @ettdro Please view profile, Network profile for contact info and to consider our free downloadable Utility Scripts for performance tuning.  Please post results of findfragtables.sql and find-redundant-indexes.sql for analysis.

Comment: @ettdro  Could you post TEXT results from Ubuntu of ulimit -a (for current limits by OS).

Comment: I finally found what was my problem actually, I was making WAY too much requests to the database, that I wasn't seeing. With Laravel DebugBar I have found them :)

Comment: Rate Per Second = RPS    
Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section    
    query_cache_size=0
    key_buffer_size=16M
    sort_buffer_size=1M
    read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 1M to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 85,937

Post ulimit -a report for consideration of OS 'Open Files' capacity to support your level of tables_opened.

Thanks for the update above.  We can still assist with more specifics to reduce WAIT time.